# Build Entity connection string from ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

In my web site I have regular [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286484.aspx) connection string like:
,

now [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ef) added it's own connection string to same database.

How is it possible to use only one [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286484.aspx) connection string and build Entity Connection string in runtime?

Comment: I belive entity connection string adds metadata to connection string therefore not sure if you can use ADO.NET as Entity Connection string

Comment: I need take data from ADO.NET and bind Entity connection string, based on ADO.NET

Answer (score 3):

you can use EntityConnectionStringBuilder to generate connection string at runtime dynamically at runtime  but you still need metada for this

```
EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder =
    new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
    //Set the provider name.
    entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;

    // Set the provider-specific connection string.
    entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

    // Set the Metadata location.
    entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/AdventureWorksModel.csdl|
                                res://*/AdventureWorksModel.ssdl|
                                res://*/AdventureWorksModel.msl";
using (EntityConnection conn =
    new EntityConnection(entityBuilder.ToString()))
{
    conn.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Just testing the connection.");
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: How can I build this Entity connection string based on ADO.NET connection string?

Comment: the connection string is still just a connection string you just need to have Provider, ProviderConnectionString like user info and so on and Metadata you can get by manually creating EF connection string and the copy that metadata to you entityBuilder.Metadata at runtime